# Grammar checking program for LibreOffice

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice

Is there a tool for checking grammar in LibreOffice?

Comment: We are not familiar with this "Ginger in windows" of which you speak. Which grammar to you want to check? Natural language (which)? A computer language grammar?

Comment: No! just english grammar. Ginger is a grammar checking software in Windows. now i know there is extension in LibreOffice though, through @Err Hunter.

Comment: Sorry. Just asking about Language Tool Extension in LibreOffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## LanguageTool extension for LibreOffice:

You need to install **LanguageTool** extension to  achieve grammar check in LibreOffice.

Get it from here : https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/languagetool

And HowTo on install extension can be found here : http://www.libreoffice.org/assets/Uploads/EN_Documents/Installingextensions.pdf

## Other extensions:

For more alternatives, have a look at this source link:

SOURCE : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-libreoffice-extensions-to-help-you-catch-grammar-problems/1280/

Answer (score -1):

Firstly allow Universe repository and update:

- [How do I enable the “Universe” repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

---

In LibreOffice Writer, you may install the desired language from menu *Tools -> Language*.
[image: snap1]

---

### [myspell](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/ooo-myspell/)

> **Documented Description:**
>   MySpell is a simple spell checker that uses affix compression and is modelled after the spell checker ispell. MySpell was written to explore how affix compression can be implemented.
>
> The Main features of MySpell are:
>
> Written in C++ to make it easier to interface with Pspell, OpenOffice, AbiWord, etc.
>       It is stateless, uses no static variables and should be completely reentrant with almost no ifdefs.
>       It tries to be as compatible with ispell to the extent it can. It can read slightly modified versions of munched ispell dictionaries (and it comes with a munched english wordlist borrowed from Kevin Atkinson's excellent Aspell.
>       It uses a heavily modified aff file format that can be derived from ispell aff files but uses the iso-8859-X character sets only.
>       It is simple with lots of comments that describes how the affixes are stored and tested for (based on the approach used by ispell).
>       It supports improved suggestions with replacement tables and ngram-scoring based mechanisms in addition to the main suggestion mechanisms.
>       Like ispell it has a BSD license (and no advertising clause).

---

### [GNU Aspell](http://aspell.net/)

> **Documented Description:**
>    GNU Aspell is a spell-checker which can be used either as a standalone application or embedded in other programs.  Its main feature is that it does a
>    much better job of suggesting possible spellings than just about any other spell-checker available for the English language, including Ispell and
>    Microsoft Word.  It also has many other technical enhancements over Ispell such as using shared memory for dictionaries and intelligently handling
>    personal dictionaries when more than one Aspell process is open at once.

- [Available Aspell Dictionaries](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html)

---

### [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/)

> **Documented Description:**
>   Hunspell is a spell checker and morphological analyzer library and program designed for languages with rich morphology and complex word compounding or
>    character encoding. It is based on MySpell and features an Ispell-like terminal interface using Curses library, an Ispell pipe interface and an
>    OpenOffice.org UNO module.
>
> Hunspell is the spell checker of LibreOffice, OpenOffice.org, Mozilla Firefox 3 & Thunderbird, Google Chrome, and it is also used by proprietary software packages, like Mac OS X, InDesign, memoQ, Opera and SDL Trados.
>
> *Main features:*
>
> - Unicode support (first 65535 Unicode character)
> - morphological analysis (in custom item and arrangement style)
> - Max. 65535 affix classes and twofold affix stripping (for agglutinative languages, like Azeri, Basque, Estonian, Finnish, Hungarian, Turkish, etc.)
> - Support complex compoundings (for example, Hungarian and German)
> - Support language specific algorithms (for example, handling Azeri and Turkish dotted i, or German sharp s)
> - Handling conditional affixes, circumfixes, fogemorphemes, forbidden words, pseudoroots and homonyms.
> - Interfaces and ports: AndroidHunspellService (for Android, based on the Chromium fork of Hunspell), Enchant (Generic spelling library from the Abiword project), XSpell (Mac OS X port, but Hunspell is part of the OS X from version 10.6 (Snow Leopard), and now it is enough to place the Hunspell dictionary files into `~/Library/Spelling or /Library/Spelling` for spell checking), Delphi, Java (JNA, JNI), Perl, .NET, Python, Ruby, UNO, RichEdit.

---

### [Ispell](http://www.lasr.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/ispell.html)

> **Documented Description:** 
>   International Ispell (an interactive spelling corrector)
>    Ispell corrects spelling in plain text, LaTeX, sgml/html/xml, and nroff files. [x]Emacs and jed have nice interfaces to ispell, and ispell works from
>    many other tools and from the command line as well.
>
> No ispell dictionaries are included in this package; you must install at least one of them ("iamerican" is recommended by default for no good reason);
>    install the "ispell-dictionary" package(s) for the language(s) you and your users will want to spell-check.
>
> It's a good idea to install "word list" package(s) for the same language(s), because they'll be used by ispell's (L)ookup command.

Comment: Grammar != spelling...

Comment: I believe this is a potentially useful answer to some totally different question about checking spelling. If it or something similar to it has not already been posted as an answer to such a question, then it probably should.