# Is there a Grammar checker for LibreOffice on Ubuntu?

Tags: libreoffice, spell-checking

I have been looking to install spell checkers on LibreOffice but I could not find any stand alone Grammar checkers for LibreOffice.

Does anyone know any Grammar checker, like Grammarly, for Ubuntu?

There was a solution posted on [Grammar checking program for LibreOffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417938/grammar-checking-program-for-libreoffice/417974#417974) but that required Java to be installed.

I am looking for a Grammar checker that does not need additional features installed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand why this question is marked as duplicate? If you read the question, it is clearly a question about Ubuntu, not LibreOffice. I too need to know this but for Ubuntu (so that everything on Ubuntu including skype, documents, notes gets checked for GRAMMER and not only spelling.)

Comment: @KumarA. The answers that the question asked were about LibreOffice, since the first sentence of the question post is about LibreOffice particularly. I personally agree with closing this as a duplicate. I've since edited the question title. I think there should be a new post about grammar checkers in general (like Grammarly).

Answer (score 2):

[image: Showing spelling and grammar]Yes

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-lightproof-en
```

See:  https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/libreoffice-lightproof-en

> Lightproof grammar checker for LibreOffice (English)

And: https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/lightproof-editor

And [Grammar checking program for LibreOffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417938/grammar-checking-program-for-libre-office/417974)

Comment: Grammar check is not perfect it tends to do better as you type. You can file a bug report if you wish

Comment: I just installed lightproof using the command prompt but LibreOffice didn't distinguish between "their" and "there" and "where" and "we're" (see image: https://i.imgur.com/MQWDzaR.png)

How do I submit a bug report?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug and https://askubuntu.com/questions/417938/grammar-checking-program-for-libre-office/417974