# Is there a grammar checking tool for Ubuntu (not only for LibreOffice)?

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice, skype, spell-checking

I know this, let's assume to be a duplicate question and an answer was already posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973030/is-there-a-grammar-checker-for-ubuntu), but my question is entirely different.

I want to know if there is a grammar (not only spell) checking tool (for English) available to be installed on Ubuntu, so that its use is not limited to only LibreOffice, but also can be used for Skype (or other messaging apps), documents (LibreOffice, WPS Office, Geany), notes, memos, everything.

I would be thankful to everyone who tries to answer - or corrects me, or lets me know if this question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out the [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/) project. You can download and install the [LanguageTool Desktop version for offline use](https://languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-4.1.zip), which lets you check for grammar and spelling errors on the desktop.
After download of the LanguageTool file - unzip the file and start languagetool.jar by double-clicking it.
Notes : LanguageTool requires Java 8 or later to be installed | [Comparison of LanguageTool Editions](https://languagetool.org/compare)

Comment: Thanks, @cl-netbox, cant this installed in the system so that we can work on whatever app (Geany, WPS writer, skype) and it gets checked for the grammar (same as Grammarly does in a browser)?

Comment: @KumarA. : As far as I do understand it, the grammar checking functionality of the desktop version should work for (nearly) all applications by starting the languagetool.jar file (if Java 8+ is installed) - just try it out. :)

Comment: unfortunately not, I have kept this jar file started and expecting this to work on Geany, but no luck. I alternatively need to write inside the console, check for grammar and then copy it to wherever I need. This is a time taking process :(

Answer (score 0):

There is also  [Antidote](http://www.antidote.info/) (commercial software, sold for €119) which supports numbers of applications even LaTeX documents!

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNCO9bGH3Ak) is a review (in french) using Linux.

[image: Screenshot from the review]

Comment: Antidote appears to be a package for sale. Most users here expect free software.

Comment: There was no such requirement in the question. Granted, when suggesting a tool that costs 119.00€, it's a really good idea to mention the price, but there's no rule against non-free programs here.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. It would be nice of you if you could maybe provide a bit more context around the program you suggested (can be in form of a quote of the developers site, or maybe even a screenshot). This would greatly improve this post in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

For a command line solution, you could install the `link-grammar` package (`sudo apt-get install link-grammar`).

Usage examples:

```sh
$ echo 'I early wake up today.' | link-parser
link-grammar: Info: Dictionary found at /usr/share/link-grammar/en/4.0.dict
link-grammar: Info: Dictionary version 5.11.0, locale en_US.UTF-8
link-grammar: Info: Library version link-grammar-5.12.0. Enter "!help" for help.
No complete linkages found.
Found 12 linkages (12 had no P.P. violations) at null count 1
    Linkage 1, cost vector = (UNUSED=1 DIS= 0.00 LEN=9)

    +-----------------Xp----------------+
    +-------->WV-------->+---MVpn---+   |
    +->Wd--+-----Sp*i----+-MVa-+    |   |
    |      |             |     |    |   |
LEFT-WALL I.p [early] wake.v up.e today .

Bye.
```

```sh
$ echo 'I early wake up today.' | link-parser -batch
link-grammar: Info: Dictionary found at /usr/share/link-grammar/en/4.0.dict
Batch mode turned on.
link-grammar: Info: Dictionary version 5.11.0, locale en_US.UTF-8
link-grammar: Info: Library version link-grammar-5.12.0. Enter "!help" for help.
+++++ error 1
1 error.
Bye.
```